# How do you efficiently sum the occurences of a value in one array at positions in another array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pytorch

Im looking for an efficient 'for loop' avoiding solution that solves an array related problem I'm having. I want to use a huge 1Darray `(A -> size = 250.000)` of values between 0 and 40 for indexing in one dimension, and a array (B) with the same size with values between 0 and 9995 for indexing in a second dimension.

The result should be an array with size (41, 9996) with for each index the amount of times that any value from array 1 occurs at a value from array 2.

Example:

```
A = [0, 3, 2, 4, 3]
B = [1, 2, 2, 0, 2]
which should result in:
[[0, 1, 0,
 [0, 0, 0,
 [0, 0, 1,
 [0, 0, 2,
 [1, 0, 0]]
```

The dirty way is too slow as the amount of data is huge, what you would be able to do is:

```py
out = np.zeros(41,9995)
for i in A:
  for j in B:
     out[i,j] += 1
```

which will take 238.000 * 238.000 loops...
I've tried this, which works partially:

```py
out = np.zeros(41,9995)
out[A,B] += 1
```

Which generates a result with 1 everywhere, regardless of the amount of times the values occur.

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a [sparse tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html):

```py
import torch

A = [0, 3, 2, 4, 3]
B = [1, 2, 2, 0, 2]
idx = torch.LongTensor([A, B])
torch.sparse.FloatTensor(idx, torch.ones(idx.shape[1]), torch.Size([5,3])).to_dense()
```

Output:

> ```
> tensor([[0., 1., 0.],
>         [0., 0., 0.],
>         [0., 0., 1.],
>         [0., 0., 2.],
>         [1., 0., 0.]])
> ```

You can also do the same with [scipy sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

coo_matrix((np.ones(len(A)), (np.array(A), np.array(B))), shape=(5,3)).toarray()
```

output:

> ```
> array([[0., 1., 0.],
>        [0., 0., 0.],
>        [0., 0., 1.],
>        [0., 0., 2.],
>        [1., 0., 0.]])
> ```

Sometimes it is better to leave the matrix in its sparse representation, rather than forcing it to be "dense" again.

Answer (score 3):

Use [numpy.add.at](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
import numpy as np

A = [0, 3, 2, 4, 3]
B = [1, 2, 2, 0, 2]

arr = np.zeros((5, 3))
np.add.at(arr, (A, B), 1)

print(arr)
```

**Output**

```
[[0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 2.]
 [1. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the numbers are in a small range, `bincount` would be a good choice for bin-based summing -

```
def accumulate_coords(A,B):
    nrows = A.max()+1
    ncols = B.max()+1
    return np.bincount(A*ncols+B,minlength=nrows*ncols).reshape(-1,ncols)
```

Sample run -

```
In [55]: A
Out[55]: array([0, 3, 2, 4, 3])

In [56]: B
Out[56]: array([1, 2, 2, 0, 2])

In [58]: accumulate_coords(A,B)
Out[58]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```